# Backpack 4.1 doesn't have "prefix" option for columns

Tags: laravel-backpack

I wanted to add an icon to a column in the LIST operation depending on a condition. I know about the `prefix` attribute for fields but it doesn't exist for columns, although in the docs it is stated:

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-columns#text

Checking the code in github, prefix support for columns has disappeared from 4.0 to 4.1.

Does anyone know if there is a reason for that? And how do you do it in the official way? I know I can override the view...

Cheers!

Comment: For me, the prefix option worked when using type 'model_function', but not for type 'select'...